# Pass a function as an argument for comparing elements in merge sort in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, templates, comparator

**EDIT 1**
Based on the comments below, I have now tried to implement using the `functors`. I am still stuck, so any kind of help would be appreciated. Here is my implementation:

mysorting.h

```
................
#include<myutils.h>
// =================================
// the actual class

class Sorting {
    public:
        template <typename T, typename Func> static void mergeSort(T *, int, Func);
};

template static void Sorting::mergeSort<int, CompareInt>(int *, int, CompareInt);
......................
```

So, I am passing the third argument as a `functor` which I have defined in my `myutils.h`. Also, I have instantiated the template for `mergeSort` to work for `int`. 
Also, I have instantiated the template for the merge function that I am using to merge the arrays in `myutils.h`. Here is a snippet from my `myutils.h`:

```
................
template <typename T, typename Func> void merge(T[], T[], int, T[], int, Func);

// functor for comparing he integers
struct CompareInt {
    int operator() (int a, int b) {
        return a-b;
    }
};

template void merge<int, CompareInt>(int[], int[], int, int[], int, CompareInt);
........................
```

The snippet from `myutils.cpp` is as follows:

```
.......................
template <typename T, typename Func> void merge(T t[], T first[], int fL, T sec[], int sL, Func compar) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    // while both the arrays have the elements left ..
    while (j < fL && k < sL) {
        if (compar(first[j], sec[k]) < 0) {
            memcpy(t + i, sec + j, sizeof(T));
            i++; j++;
        } else {
            memcpy(t + i, sec + k, sizeof(T));
            i++; k++;
        }
    }

    ...........
    }
}
.......................
```

And the snippet from `mysorting.cpp` is as follows:

```
...............................
class Sorting {
    public:
        template <typename T, typename Func> static void mergeSort(T *, int, Func);
};

template <typename T, typename Func> void Sorting::mergeSort(T *arr, int l, Func compar) { ...}
..........................
```

I am simply calling :

```
CompareInt c;
Sorting::mergeSort(arr, 5, c);
```

to run the sort function. When I try to compile my code using my `Makefile`, I get the following error:

```
g++ -c -g -Wall -I./include -c src/mysorting.cpp  -o src/mysorting.o
In file included from src/mysorting.cpp:2:0:
./include/myutils.h: In instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’:
./include/myutils.h:19:79:   required from here
./include/myutils.h:19:79: error: explicit instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
 template void merge<int, CompareInt>(int[], int[], int, int[], int, CompareInt);
                                                                               ^
./include/myutils.h: In instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’:
./include/myutils.h:19:79:   required from here
./include/myutils.h:19:79: error: explicit instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
./include/myutils.h: In instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’:
./include/myutils.h:19:79:   required from here
./include/myutils.h:19:79: error: explicit instantiation of ‘void merge(T*, T*, int, T*, int, Func) [with T = int; Func = CompareInt]’ but no definition available [-fpermissive]
make: *** [src/mysorting.o] Error 1
```

Can you please give me some hints on this?

**ORIGINAL**

I am trying to write a static function in my class `Sorting` in cpp for implementing merge sort. I have already implemented it the merge sort for sorting an integer array. Now, I am trying to implement the merge sort using `Templates` to sort the arrays of any datatype. For that, I am trying to pass an additional argument as a `compar` function in the `mergeSort` function. Here is the implementation:

The header file is as follows:

```
................
class Sorting {
    public:
        template <typename T> static void mergeSort(T *,int, int (*)(const void*,const void*));
};
................
```

The cpp file is as follows:

```
class Sorting {
    public:
        template <typename T> static void mergeSort(T *,int, int (*)(const void*,const void*));
};

.......

template <typename T> void Sorting::mergeSort(T *arr, int l, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)) {
    // if the lengh of the array is 1, it is already sorted. Case, when the array is
    // empty
    if (l <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    // else, we divide the arrays and recurse..
    T *left = new T[l/2];
    T *right = new T[l - l/2];

    // copying the values into the left and the right arrays..
    memcpy(left, arr, l/2 * sizeof(T));
    memcpy(right, arr + l/2, (l - l/2) * sizeof(T));

    // running merge sort on the lef tand the right arrays separately ..
    mergeSort(left, l/2, compar);
    mergeSort(right, l - l/2, compar);

    merge(arr, left, l/2, right, l - l/2, compar);
}
```

Implementation of the `merge` function is as follows:

```
template <typename T> void merge(T t[], T first[], int fL, T sec[], int sL, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*)) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    // while both the arrays have the elements left ..
    while (j < fL && k < sL) {
        if ((*compar)(first + j, sec + k) < 0) {
            memcpy(t + i, sec + j, sizeof(T));
            i++; j++;
        } else {
            memcpy(t + i, sec + k, sizeof(T));
            i++; k++;
        }
    }

    // while only the first array has the elements left
    while(j < fL) {
        memcpy(t + i, sec + j, sizeof(T));
        i++; j++;
    }

    // while only the second array has the elements left
    while(k < fL) {
        memcpy(t + i, sec + k, sizeof(T));
        i++; k++;
    }
}
```

And finally, my `main.cpp` is as follows:

```
................
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};
    Sorting::mergeSort(arr, 5, compare);    
}
...............
```

When I am trying to compile the code with the `Makefile`, it gives me the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void Sorting::mergeSort<int>(int*, int, int (*)(void const*, void const*))", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

The code got successfully compiled when I ran my function specifically for the integers, but now I have some troubles. Any idea?

Comment: Whats with all the `void*`'s?  Part of the reason to use C++ and templates is to have type safety and not have to use `void*`'s.

Comment: Why do you have the class definition in both the header and cpp? Also, to see the root of your problem, you can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Use functors rather than passing functions.

Comment: Also, if `T` is a `std::string` or any non-POD type, your code will not work properly.   For example, you would be calling `memcpy` on an array of `std::string`'s, and that is not going to work.  I believe you've been reading 'C' material with all of the `void *` usage and the use of memcpy, or at least a 'C' implementation of merge sort.  C++ is a different language.

Comment: If using `void*`is not the correct way then why the implementation of `qsort()`in `cstdlib` done this way? It also requires a comparator function with `void*`as arguments.

Comment: @Swapnil `qsort()` is a C function, this is C++.

Comment: I have now implemented the same thing using functors as suggested by Eissa.

Comment: This is my struct for acting as the functor: 
`struct CompareInt {
 int operator() (int a, int b) {
  return a-b;
 }
};`

Comment: When I try to compile now it gives me the following error:
`
g++ -g -Wall src/mysorting.o src/myutils.o main.o -o a.out
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void Sorting::mergeSort<int, CompareInt>(int*, int, CompareInt)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
`